# GET and POST fields in the same table

Tags: html, forms, html-table

The following is a fairly typical layout for admin pages (e.g. searching in a database and doing something with the results):

- action dropdown
- table header row with column names
- second table header row with search filters for columns
- result rows with a checkbox
- search button

The user can set all sorts of filters, search, select some of the results with the checkboxes, then select an action from the dropdown, and the action and the selected row ids will be submitted to some processing script.

There are some basic expectations for such a control:

- GET for searches, POST for actions
- use the auto-sizing features of HTML tables so that columns can be narrow or wide depending on the content
- reasonably cross-browser

I have been looking for a nice technique to achieve this, but everything I can think of seems to have serious disadvantages:

- the simplest would be having two forms (a GET form for the search controls and a POST for the checkboxes), but the HTML4 DTD makes that impossible: I can either wrap the whole table in a single form or put separate forms inside every table cell (which is pretty useless).
- alternately, I could use a different table element for every row and group them freely into forms, but then the column widths would not match and I would have to set fixed widths. (CSS3 `table-*` display types lack adequate support.)
- HTML5 allows us to place input elements outside forms, and connect them with the `form` attribute, but that has even less support.
- There is an ugly hack involving invalid HTML with forms directly wrapping `tr` elements, which seems to work but messes up the DOM, confuses Javascript libraries and is not exactly future-safe.
- I can wrap the whole table in a single form, and change its method and action dynamically depending on which button was pressed, but that makes me dependent on Javascript; also, I don't want to submit search controls in the POST request and vice versa, it is unnecessary traffic. Also, when there are a lot of result rows, the search request might surpass the URL size limitations (just a few thousand characters in IE) because of all the checkboxes.
- I could do the same but disable the unnecessary fields when the user submits the form. Beyond being horribly overcomplicated for such a simple task, this has various usability problems when the request is somehow stopped (e.g. user pressing ESC) and the user is left with a bunch if disabled form fields.

Is there a better solution I am not aware of?

Comment: Sounds overly complicated... no way to simplify the form or decompose it so you can have separate "postable" and "gettable" versions served up differently?

Comment: @Marc B: I don't see a way with the current design.

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX. It allows you to define your own get/post data that is not form-dependent.

Comment: AJAX behaves slightly differently from real submits (e.g. no back button navigation, no form history), which is again bad for usability. It can be worked around to some extent, but that is very cumbersome (IE iframe-based history emulation, ugh.)